# How to identify from where the contextItemDoubleClick event triggers

Tags: c#, enterprise-architect

I want to identify from where the **ContextItemDoubleClick** event is triggering in enterprise architect . (For eg) if i double click on a project browser in EA i need to identify it was triggered from project browser , because now **ContextItemDoubleClick** is triggering whenever user doubleclicks inside EA . Is it possible to identify that it triggers from project browser or open diagram or diagram object ?

Answer (score 1):

No, you can't. At least not from EA:

> This event occurs when a user has double-clicked (or pressed the Enter key) on the item in context, either in a diagram, in the Project Browser or in a custom compartment. Add-Ins to handle events can subscribe to this broadcast function.

You won't likely analyze the current screen contents and make a guess where the mouse cursor is positioned, will you?

Ask yourself (or tell us) why you want to do that to find some alternative solution for your underlying issue.