# EA Element right click option disable

Tags: enterprise-architect

1. Is there any Api's from which we will be able to know an Element is Double clicked from EA Project browser or an element is Double clicked from EA Diagram workspace.
2. Is there any Api's or method from which we can disable right click option on elements from EA Diagram workspace.

Comment: why do you want to disable right-clicking?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to identify from where the contextItemDoubleClick event triggers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44253984/how-to-identify-from-where-the-contextitemdoubleclick-event-triggers)

Answer (score 1):

1. AFAIR this had been asked also on Sparx forum and the answer was: you can't except you find out the mouse position and get the positions of the diagram and browser windows. The help on `EA_OnContextItemDoubleClicked` confirms

> This event occurs when a user has double-clicked (or pressed the Enter key) on the item in context, either in a diagram, in the Project Browser or in a custom compartment. Add-Ins to handle events can subscribe to this broadcast function.

2. No. `EA_OnContextItemChanged` has no way to tell EA anything. In contrast (same issue as above) if you can figure out that it's from the diagram `EA_OnContextItemDoubleClicked` can tell EA that you have handled everything and it will not open the properties. But that does not work for context menu clicks.

Comment: You can only do something about your own add-in context menu options. EA doesn't allow you to change any of the other context menu options (except for disabling menu options in general via *workspaces and commands*)

Comment: @GeertBellekens I'm not that familiar with Windows internals. So you should post that as answer too.